# 'ListBlogPost' object has no attribute 'get_object' django

Tags: python, django

I am using forms in my list view for review post before it publish. If I select publish then it will be show in my template otherwise not. It's seems to me everything okay. But why I am getting this error `'ListBlogPost' object has no attribute 'get_object'`. Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
class ListBlogPost(ListView,FormView):
       model = Blog
       template_name = 'approval-blog-post.html'
       form_class = AdminBlogFrom
       
       def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('approval-blog')

       #def get_object(self,slug): #Sarath Chandran added this as you mentioned but didn't work
          #blog = get_object_or_404(Blog,slug=slug)
          #return  blog
  
       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          data = super(ListBlogPost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
          data['blog_admin_form'] = AdminBlogFrom()
          
          return data
      
       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Your Comment pending for admin approval')
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Somethings Wrong. Please try again')
            return self.form_invalid(form)

       def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ListBlogPost, self).form_valid(form)
```

**froms.py**

```
class AdminBlogFrom(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['is_published','author','slug']
```

**models.py**

```
 author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=100)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True)
 body = RichTextUploadingField()
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True)
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True,blank=True,null=True)
 updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True,blank=True,null=True)
 CHOICES = (
        ('published', 'published',),
        ('pending', 'pending',),
        ('rejected', 'rejected',),
        )
 is_published = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=CHOICES,default='pending'
      )
```

**#approve-post.html**

```
<form  method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<button class="btn btn-info">Publish</button>
</form>
```

When I am clicking on publish button I am getting this errror `ListBlogPost' object has no attribute 'object_list'`

Comment: In `views.py` in `ListBlogPost` class in method `post` you are calling `self.object = self.get_object()` and `get_object` is not defined for this class and class you inherited from.

Comment: Thanks Relandom. How to define `get_object` ??

Comment: And why do you need this method? Won't it work if you remove this line? I might be wrong but I think you don't need/use it

Comment: Relandom  I must be use forms in my list view.

Comment: I guess something wrong in this line ` self.object = self.get_object()`

Comment: I mean this line: `self.object = self.get_object()` - what happens if you remove it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233667/discussion-between-boyenec-and-relandom).

Answer (score 1):

The 'self' in the class ListBlogPost  is referring to this class ListBlogPost.
so either the get_object() method should be part of This class or it should be part of ListView or FormView from where this class is inherited. since it is no where this error is getting created.

you can define get_object()  in the class like this:

```
class ListBlogPost(ListView,FormView):
       model = Blog
       template_name = 'approval-blog-post.html'
       form_class = AdminBlogFrom
       
       def get_object(self,pk):
           // add your logic here
       
       def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('approval-blog')
  
       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          data = super(ListBlogPost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
          data['blog_admin_form'] = AdminBlogFrom()
          
          return data
      
       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Your Comment pending for admin approval')
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Somethings Wrong. Please try again')
            return self.form_invalid(form)

       def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ListBlogPost, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks Sarath Chandran K for your answare. Tried this `def get_object(self,slug): blog = get_object_or_404(Blog,slug=slug)` but didn't work

Comment: can you please share me the what exactly you are trying to do.  are you trying to select a BlogPost and publish it, or you are trying to create a BlogPost.

Comment: Tried this `def get_object(self,slug): blog = get_object_or_404(Blog,slug=slug)return  blog` and now getting this error `get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'`

Comment: in the post method are you getting the value of slug. if so pass that value to get_object() method

Comment: Sarath Chandran K  I updated my question. Please see..Still now not working..now getting this error after add your logic `get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'`